# Calling C++ std::sort on a vector of struct pointers

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, function-pointers

*edited to add error messages

Visual Studio's intellisense is red flagging the sort function when I call it on a vector of pointers to a struct that I've defined earlier in the program.

I've instantiated a function pointer to my comparison method and am calling sort as follows:

```
bool(*compareNodes)(nodePtr, nodePtr) = compNodes;

sort(frontier.begin(), frontier.end(), compNodes);

/* flags compnodes and sort; "cannot determine which instance of overloaded 
 * function "compNodes is intended" */
```

compNodes function:

```
static bool compNodes(nodePtr Node1, nodePtr Node2){
    if (Node1->fValue != Node2->fValue)
        return (Node1->fValue < Node2->fValue);
    else
        return (Node1->ID > Node2->ID);
}
```

Comment: And you care about what Intellisense does because...?

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Is there an error message?

Comment: Please add the error message into your question. Sometimes, IntelliSense is wrong and the code compiles fine.

Comment: The error message implies that you have more than one `compNodes` function in your program, show us the other one.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. That's what had me stumped. I had a function prototype that was confusing it, I think; commenting it out fixed everything fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wild guess: `compNodes` is overloaded. You smartly tried getting a pointer to the right overload with `compareNodes`, but you're not actually using it in `std::sort()`. Change the line to:

```
sort(frontier.begin(), frontier.end(), compareNodes);
```

If your warning level was high enough, you'd see that `compareNodes` is currently unused.

Comment: Wow, did not catch that. That fixed things, and I get to keep my function prototype this way as well!